# Force function to show result when they received with jquery.get method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

this function gets results with $.get method from an asp ashx XML file :

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/example.ashx",
                { From: txtFrom, To: txtTo, Date: txtTime },
                function (data) {
                    var arrFrom = [], arrTo = [], arrPrice = [];
                    $(data).find("F").each(function (index, item) {
                        arrFrom[index] = [];
                        arrTo[index] = [];
                        arrPrice[index] = [];
                        $(item).find("From").each(function (i, fromIndex) {
                            arrFrom[index].push($(fromIndex).text());
                        });
                        $(item).find("To").each(function (i, toIndex) {
                            arrTo[index].push($(toIndex).text());
                        });
                        $(item).find("Price").each(function (i, priceIndex) {
                            arrPrice[index].push($(priceIndex).text());
                        });
                    });
                    /**********************************************************/
                    var htmlResult = "<table style=\"background-color:red;\">";
                    for (i = 0; i < arrFrom.length; i++) {
                        htmlResult += "<tr><td>" + arrFrom[i] + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrTo[i] + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + arrPrice[i] + "</td></tr>"
                    };
                    htmlResult += "</table>";

                    $('#divSearchResults').html(htmlResult);
                    /**********************************************************/

                }, "text");
```

but ashx needs some time (unpredictable) to response.
I used a function to recall this each 5seconds, but it is not affordable.
how can I make htmlResult be created right when the response is received?

Comment: If you replay this call, you're actually making another call to your backend, possibly extending the time it takes for it to answer. Your code should work just like you asked as it is.

Comment: Except that you're redeclaring `htmlResult` just before using it. Remove the last `var htmlResult;`

Comment: as jquery docs I tried .done after that, but no luck. would you please refer to a sample?

Comment: Please explain how is this not working. It should work as it is.

Comment: example.ashx need some time to response, but GET method won't wait for the response and htmlResult is always empty.
I think there must be somthing like : Get -> receiveRespose -> showHtmlResults.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code is correct, in the sense that the anonymous function that you've defined fires as soon as your backend responds. If your data is empty, it could mean that something happens to the data while you're processing it in your javascript, your backend returned an empty dataset, or your backend timed out. To check whether the problem is with your backend or your data processing, try this:

```
$.get("http://www.example.com/example.ashx",
    { From: txtFrom, To: txtTo, Date: txtTime },
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //Or in case you don't have a developer console use alert:
        alert(data);
    }, "text");
```

You should now be able to verify that you are indeed getting data. If that's the case, then something is happening to the data when you're parsing it, and you should debug that code instead, perhaps with a static dataset. You could also make your life a lot easier by sending json encoded data instead of plaintext. I don't know how you would do that with your backend but I'm sure Google will help. On the javascript side of things you could then change the last line to:

```
    }, "json");
```

Then, instead of `find()`ing things, you would have a neat json object to work with.